# SQL Server 2008 - To Insert/Update in Main table from Staging table

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, sqlbulkcopy

Once the data is imported in a Staging table through Bulk Insert, then I need to do two steps:

1. Transformations
2. Insert/Update in Main table

Is the JOINS are the best tool OR there is something quicker/more efficient to perform these tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

- make your transformations on that staging table (add additional columns as needed etc.)
- do the INSERT/UPDATE into the actual data table using the [SQL Server 2008 `MERGE` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) which is ideally suited for just this - update some existing rows, insert some new rows (and possibly delete some old "orphaned" rows). It's a single command which can handle just about all insert, update, delete scenario in a single call

See some great articles on how to use the `MERGE` command:

- [Using SQL Server 2008's MERGE statement](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/sqlserver/soa/Using-SQL-Server-2008-s-MERGE-statement/0,339028455,339283059,00.htm)
- [SQL Server – 2008 – Introduction to Merge Statement – One Statement for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/)
- [Merge Statement in SQL Server 2008](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQL-2008-Merge-Statement.aspx)